# Can I expand all nodes in Memgraph lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

My query returns quite large number of nodes, but I'd like to expand them anyway. Is there Expand all command in Memgraph Lab? I can't find one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to do that. You could click on each node and click "Expand" but that would take time and it is not efficient at all.

A possible workaround is with Cypher. let's say you have a Cypher query that returns nodes and edges that are your base for the graph view, e.g.

This is on a [Pandora Papers dataset](https://playground.memgraph.com/sandbox/pandora-papers), a query to get people having connections to Qatar.

```
MATCH path=(:Officer)-->(country:Country)
WHERE country.iso_2_code = "QA"
RETURN path;
```

You can then just remove RETURN path and replace it with WITH path to get level 1 expand on all nodes.

```
MATCH path=(:Officer)-->(country:Country)
WHERE country.iso_2_code = "QA"
WITH path
MATCH (n)-[e]->(m)
WHERE n IN nodes(path) OR m IN nodes(path)
RETURN n, e, m;
```

You can do the same if you are not having path in the first query, but n as node, e.g.

```
MATCH (officer:Officer)-->(country:Country)
WHERE country.iso_2_code = "QA"
WITH collect(officer) + collect(country) as nodes
MATCH (n)-[e]->(m)
WHERE n IN nodes OR m IN nodes
RETURN n, e, m;
```